# Xcode 5.1 errors for incompatible type

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm not positive that this is related to Xcode 5.1.  I have addressed all the 64-bit related warnings due to NSInteger, etc, but I moved some existing code into a new project and I'm hitting some unexpected warnings related to pointer types.  This example comes from GCDAsyncSocket.m:

```
uint8_t *preBuffer;
size_t preBufferSize;
...
preBufferSize = <some number>;
preBuffer = malloc(preBufferSize);
```

This generates the error:

```
GCDAsyncSocket.m:398:13: Assigning to 'uint8_t *' (aka 'unsigned char *') from incompatible type 'void *'
```

I know how to fix this error but my question is, has Xcode 5.1 changed the rules when it comes to implicit conversions between pointer types?  I tried to find a setting in previous projects that might explain the fact that it compiled without warning, let alone error, in the past but I didn't find anything.

This is just one example among many.  If anybody can shed any light on why this error pops up now, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Are you sure this is being compiled as (Objective-)C and not (Objective-)C++?

Comment: It isn't necessary for C, see for example [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Compiling `char *p = malloc(12);` in `test.c` works for me with no flags.

Comment: Thank you @Chuck.  "Compile Sources As" was set to "Based on file type", but I also found "-x objective-c++" in the C flags.